# WP Bakery Wordpress set height from element to height of another element

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, wpbakery

I'm trying to set an element at the same height of another element.
So I thought using this method it should work:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
   var sliderHeight = document.querySelector('.slider').offsetHeight;
   document.querySelector('#alles').style.height = sliderHeight + "px";
});
```

How's it possible that this doesn't work? And is there another way achieve what I want?

Comment: _"How's it possible that this doesn't work?"_ - maybe the correct height you are looking for, has not yet been determined at the point when you execute this ...? Especially with a slider component I would not be surprised, because those often only initialize themselves after page load as well.